# Why is it more likely to get 2 heads and 1 tail when flipping a coin three times? (Without thinking of TTT vs HTH+HHT+THH)

Tags: probability

For example, it's more likely to get 2 heads and 1 tail than it is to get 3 tails in 3 coin flips.

The typical answer to this question would be: it's less likely to get 3 tails in a row than 2 heads and 1 tails because there are more possible sequences that result in the latter. To get 3 tails in a row in 3 coin flips, only the sequence TTT will satisfy us (probability is 1/8). But to get 2 heads, we could get either HTT or HTH or THH (probability is 3/8).

But every sequence is equally as likely, so why do we say that it is more likely to get one of the other three sequences than it is to get TTT?

Comment: It's just like you explained it in your second paragraph.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to argue for a $\frac12$ chance to get three tails, because either you get three tails or you get "some other sequence", and every sequence is equally likely so $TTT$ is just as likely as "some other sequence." (All I'm doing here is expanding your argument, which lumps three sequences together, to lump seven sequences together.)

Answer (score 2):

You’re right: Every sequence is equally likely. Your last sentence equivocates on the meaning of “get one of the other three sequences”. The probability to get *a particular one* of those three sequences is the same as the probability to get three tails. Hence the probability to get *any one* of those three sequences is three times that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't count $HTH$ and $HHT$ separately when counting equally-likely sequences, then you have no justification to suppose all sequences are equally likely. The "equally likely" idea comes from an analysis that counts $8$ distinct possible sequences of three coin tosses and considers that at each step the next toss is equally likely to be either $H$ or $T.$

But you *can* compute the two probabilities without enumerating all the sequences,
provided that you correctly consider *some* sequences.

First, three tails requires that three independent tosses come out as "tails". Each tail has a $\frac12$ probability, and independence means we can multiply the probabilities, so the probability of three tails is 
$\left(\frac12\right)^3 = \frac18.$

For the same reasons, the probability of three heads is also $\frac18.$

The possible numbers of heads and tails are three tails, three heads, two tails and a head, or two heads and a tail.
Since the first two outcomes have a total probability of $\frac14,$ there is a $\frac34$ probability that one of the other two outcomes will occur.

Knowing that heads and tails are equally likely on each toss, we know we are equally likely to get two heads and one tail as two tails and one head.
(After all, if we simply renamed all heads to "tails" and all tails to "heads," none of the probabilities would change.)
So each of these events has the same probability $p,$ where $p + p = \frac34.$
Therefore $p = \frac38.$

This shows that two tails and a head has probability $\frac38$ whereas three tails has a probability of only $\frac18.$ Therefore two tails and a head is more likely.

This is a cheap trick, however, which works only because the distribution is symmetric and has only four possible numbers of tails. It wouldn't work for a longer string of tosses or if the coin were unfair. In general, things work out a lot better if you just remember that $HT$ is not $TH.$